# transition graph that accepts only Λ and language a*

Tags: formal-languages, automata

I am trying to have a transition graph that accepts only Λ and also one that accepts language a* ...is this ok ???

transition graph that accepts only Λ
[image]

transition graph that accepts language a*

[image]

Comment: Please, write a little introduction to your notation. I guess Λ is the empty string? And "+" denotes an accepting state and "-" the initial state?

Comment: oh sorry...it is exactly what you said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automata you have drawn are correct, but they are redundant.

I would suggest, for a language that accepts only the empty string, a single state which is initial and accepting is enough. No other states or edges needed.

For the language that accespts $a^*$, you draw a state which is initial and accepting and you also need a looping edge for $a$.